# Locally Storing data in python

Tags: python-3.6

Am trying to create a simple app to store a user account and passwords(something like a vault) and am wondering if there is a way i can be able to store data without an external database..maybe something like localstorage since I want to be able to run the app without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got what you really need here.

But you could store what you need in a local file:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
   file.write('login:pwd')
```